# Matplotlib heat map, vertical bottom label

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to make **bottom** label of a heat map as vertical. It is horizontal as default. An example is given below;

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Thank!

Comment: add your comment as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done with

```
plt.xticks(width, heightList, rotation='vertical')
```